# How to get text of the outer most DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm creating a Chrome extension. When the user clicks on the div, it returns all the elements within the div. But I only need access to the text outside the  tags.

This is the function I wrote, but it gives me the entire text within the `<div>` tag.

```
function getData(e) {
  var li = e.currentTarget;
  return li.innerText;
}
```

```
<div class="msg">
I started painting as a hobby when I was little. I didn't know I had any talent. I   believe talent is just a pursued interest. 

Anybody can do what I do. Just go back and put one little more happy tree in there. Everybody's different. Trees are different. 

Let them all be individuals. We'll put some happy little leaves here and there. These things happen automatically. 

<reactions class="xyz">
 <reaction class="ABC">
  <span> 27 </span>
  <span> 2 </span>
  <span> 12 </span>
 </reaction>
</reactions>

</div>
```

I tried looping over the DOM elements returned, but the elements returned are so dynamic that it doesn't work.

Expected Output: I started painting as a hobby when I was little. I didn't know I had any talent. I   believe talent is just a pursued interest.

Anybody can do what I do. Just go back and put one little more happy tree in there. Everybody's different. Trees are different.

Let them all be individuals. We'll put some happy little leaves here and there. These things happen automatically.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: I just updated the original with the expected output.